# Continuity of matrix operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose $A=(a_{i,j})$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix, and consider the operator norm

$$ \|A\|_{op} = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} A \cdot x$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is some norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose that by $A \rightarrow B$ we mean that each $|a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}| \rightarrow 0$ according to the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Hypothesis:** $A \to B$ implies that $\|A\|_{op} \to \|B\|_{op}$.

---

**Proof Attempt**

Consider the Frobenius norm

$$ \| M \|_{F} = \sqrt{  \sum_{i} \sum_{j} |m_{i,j} |^{2}},$$

where again $|m_{i,j} |$ is the absolute value of $m_{i,j}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then by finite dimensions and the equvalence of norms, we have that for some constant $K>0$,

$$ \|\cdot \|_{op} \leq K \cdot \| \cdot \|_{F}.$$

Hence, by the reverse triangle inequality and the above observation,

$$| \| A \|_{op} - \| B \|_{op} | \leq \| A -B \|_{op} \leq K\cdot \| A-B \|_{F} $$

That the right hand side tends towards $0$ is then immediate from the definition of the Frobenius norm and the fact that each $|a_{i,j} - b_{i,j}| \rightarrow 0$. QED.

Does this look okay?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, I just wanted to add a more general description of the situation.

In general, if $A$ is any $C^*$-algebra and $n\geq1$ we have the inequalities

$$\sup_{i,j}\|a_{i,j}\|_A\leq\|[a_{i,j}]_{i,j}\|_{M_n(A)}\leq\sum_{i,j}\|a_{i,j}\|_A$$
where the norm of $M_n(A)$ is the operator norm. So, if a sequence of matrices converges to $0$ in the way you are describing, the right inequality yields trivially that the operator norm tends to $0$

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unaware of that general result!